# How to show products price from external websites in magento

Tags: magento

We have requirement where we need to integrate the price comparison feature on our website in magento just like the below reference link:-

http://www.zopper.com/air-conditioner/hitachi-i-clean-air-conditioner-15-ton-price-reviews-pid-3b997787#prd-prices

How can we accomplish this in magento by integration some feeds or any other way.

What we need to think through is how to use this in conjunction with data feeds from other sites / portals??

Any Suggestions would be welcome!!

Comment: Do anybody have idea how can we display the prices from other websites like snapdeal & flip kart on product detail page in magnto like the above reference link mentioned???